# d3 Choropleth map with hover effect does not display tooltip

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, geojson, topojson

I am trying to add a tooltip to the d3 Choropleth map with hover effect from this page https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/choropleth_hover_effect.html
[image: d3 Chroropleth map] The tooltip  seems to be appendend to the svg, as I can inspect the map and see an inner div with the suppossed text that should appear when hovering the countries, but when doing so, nothing shows up, even though the tooltip parameters seem to be updated on each different hover.

I've taken the tooltip from another graph as the current map I am trying to implement does not have tooltip. I've tried creating the tooltip variable within function ready(error, topo)and the styles/data inside the mouseover and mouseleave functions but it does not display the tooltip over the countries

Here is the coode in my xhtml

```
<head>
        <!-- Load d3.js and the geo projection plugin -->
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-geo-projection.v2.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                // The svg
                var svg = d3.select("svg"),
                width = +svg.attr("width"),
                height = +svg.attr("height");

                // Map and projection
                var path = d3.geoPath();
                var projection = d3.geoMercator()
                .scale(70)
                .center([0,20])
                .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

                // Data and color scale
                var data = d3.map();
                var colorScale = d3.scaleThreshold()
                .domain([100000, 1000000, 10000000, 30000000, 100000000, 500000000])
                .range(d3.schemeBlues[7]);

                // Load external data and boot
                d3.queue()
                .defer(d3.json, "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/world.geojson")
                .defer(d3.csv, "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/world_population.csv", function(d) { data.set(d.code, +d.pop); })
                .await(ready);

                var tooltip = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
                    .append("div")
                    .style("opacity", 0)
                    .attr("class", "tooltip")
                    .style("background-color", "white")
                    .style("border", "solid")
                    .style("border-width", "2px")
                    .style("border-radius", "5px")
                    .style("padding", "5px")

                function ready(error, topo) {

                    let mouseOver = function(d) {
                        d3.selectAll(".Country")
                        .transition()
                        .duration(200)
                        .style("opacity", .5)
                        d3.select(this)
                        .transition()
                        .duration(200)
                        .style("opacity", 1)
                        .style("stroke", "black")
                        tooltip.style("opacity", 1)
                            .html("The exact value of<br/>this cell is: " + d.pop)
                            .style("left", (d3.mouse(this)[0]+70) + "px")
                            .style("top", (d3.mouse(this)[1]) + "px")
                    }

                    let mouseLeave = function(d) {
                        d3.selectAll(".Country")
                        .transition()
                        .duration(200)
                        .style("opacity", .8)
                        d3.select(this)
                        .transition()
                        .duration(200)
                        .style("stroke", "transparent")
                        tooltip.style("opacity", 0)
                    }

                    // Draw the map
                    svg.append("g")
                        .selectAll("path")
                        .data(topo.features)
                        .enter()
                        .append("path")
                        // draw each country
                        .attr("d", d3.geoPath()
                            .projection(projection)
                        )
                        // set the color of each country
                        .attr("fill", function (d) {
                            d.total = data.get(d.id) || 0;
                            return colorScale(d.total);
                        })
                        .style("stroke", "transparent")
                        .attr("class", function(d){ return "Country" } )
                        .style("opacity", .8)
                        .on("mouseover", mouseOver )
                        .on("mouseleave", mouseLeave )
                }
            })
        </script>
    </head>

    <div>
        <div>
    <h1>Graphs</h1>

    <!-- Create an element where the map will take place -->
    <svg id="my_dataviz" width="400" height="300"></svg>

    </div>
    </div>
```

After rendering the map (working with just hovering function) I inspect it and can see the following.

[image: Map hovering on Russia and showing data on tooltip div over console]

If I change the country, the data on the tooltip div varies.

[image: Map hovering on EEUU and showing different data on tooltip div over console]

**--UPDATE--**

Following @enxaneta 's advice, I tried taking the div outside svg. The result is having the tooltip in a separate div. This time the tooltip appears in the page but is displayed at the bottom of the map, not over it, how I would like to see it.

[image: Tooltip outside svg]

I am still figuring out how to implement foreignObject.

**--UPDATE 2--**

Adding tooltip position absolute toke the div and put it relative to the mouse hovering. However, even though it is vertically aligned with the country selected, it is way up at the top of the page.

```
<style>
    .tooltip{position:absolute;}
</style>
```

[image: tooltip floating arround]

[image: tooltip floating arround 2]

Comment: You should either put the `<div class="tooltip"` outside the svg element or inside the svg nested in a `<foreignObject>` element

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I am new to this...in order to add the tooltip I think I do `var tooltip = d3.select("#my_dataviz").append("div") (...)` so to put it outside the svg, should I select another tag, another div for instance in the page and append it there?

Comment: if you decided to put the tooltip outside the svg element you may do `.tooltip{position:absolute;}`in the css and use the mouse position over the svg element to set the left and top properties in javascript

Comment: I think this is the right path! Still having some difficulties with the possition of the tooltip though...as I can see it moving arround but not particularli over the map, but far more up in the webpage. Nonetheless it seems it is following the same pattern as the map, as I hover over the countries, the boxes appear aligned verticaly. I tried adding `.style("postion", "relative")` to the <svg> as I read the wrapper had to be that position for the tooltip to work, but it still was showing unaligned